# Is there a more efficient method to call the Hacker News API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hacker-news-api

I am trying to find karma (points) of each Hacker News user using the [official API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API). I am new to programming.

The following is the code snippet I have written to get karma of one specific user. There are close to 300k user accounts on HN.

```
var request = require("request");

request(
    "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/pg.json",

    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body).karma);
    }
});
```

I ran this code, but it is not fast. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: where do you think the bottleneck is?

Comment: @JaromandaX Calling the Hacker News API.

Comment: the bottleneck is the amount of data that API returns - about 1 megabyte for the sample you provided

Comment: Hmm, yea. Is there a way to make the script efficient? @lexicore answered by saying that nothing much can be done here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a faster way. Use the following API endpoint:

```
https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/${username}/karma.json
```

For comparison, here are the elapsed times for the respective calls:

```
/v0/user/pg.json: 9.560ms
/v0/user/pg/karma.json: 3.061ms
```

Answer (score 1):

`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/<user>.json` is the only API endpoint to return karma.

So no, there is no better (available) way.